# Get ImageView height and width in expandable layout

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-adapter

Altough I can get the width and height of each view in the onBindViewHolder, I can not get width and height of imageView in the expandable layout. Do you have any idea why?

My xml code:

```
 <net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout
                android:id="@+id/expandable_layout_0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:el_duration="0"
                app:el_expanded="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgActivityLineChart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="82dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/backgroundGray"
                    android:text="content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            </net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout>
```

And my java code (in onBindViewHolder method):

```
    ((UserViewHolder) holder).btnExpand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View view) {

        imgwidth= userViewHolder.imgView.getWidth(); 
        imgheight= userViewHolder.imgView.getHeight();
        int test= userViewHolder.btnExpand.getHeight();

 }
        });
```

Comment: Because your ImageView is not visible that means its visibility is gone. Android doesn't draw any view with visibility gone. So you to either measure it first.

Comment: As the answer below OnGlobalLayoutListener gets called when a view is drawn over the screen. So you will be able to get the width and height of the child views of your expandableLayout

Comment: When the expandable layout is expand and the ImageView is visible, height  and width is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it is using observable to ensure that the height and width are available before you read them

```
((UserViewHolder) holder).btnExpand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

          userViewHolder.imgView.getViewTreeObserver()
            .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    userViewHolder.imgView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    width = userViewHolder.imgView.getWidth();
                    height = userViewHolder.imgView.getHeight();

                }
            });
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // Ensure you call it only once :
        yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        // Here you can get the size :)
    }
});
```

Work for me.